# Visiting Delhi, Bangkok and China in a month?

Tags: china, bangkok, new-delhi

I'm from Belgium and last year I went to Beijing for 3 months for an internship and now I want to go back to China for a **3-4 weeks** and visit a few cities. But because I've been to China already I was thinking about visiting more countries at once, because I've got a lot of places I want to visit and discover.

I made an Excel sheet with an overview of 2 of my plans:

[image: Plan sheet]

But I've never visited so many places in a short period of time.

1. Do you recommend or discourage such trip? And why?
2. I don't know that much about Delhi and Bangkok, so do you think that I could visit the most important places in only that small period of time or don't you think it is worth just visiting it for just just 7-10 days each?
3. Other opinions/hints/advices about all this?

Comment: Seems a bit short for Zhangjiajie (2 full days if everything goes perfectly). If you have the energy (given your age, you should have) this could be a worthwhile thing to do (better than not going at all, in my opinion, and might point where you want to return to later) but keep in mind if you get sick (say in India) it could be a bit of disaster.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany How much time do you recommend for Zhangjiajie? I've been to Guilin last year, and I was there 3 full days and I saw everything I wanted to see.

Comment: Three full days should be enough. The flights in and out of DYG are quite limited, and surface transport (eg. from Changsha) takes many hours so I suggest erring on the high side.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Ok, maybe if I take 3 full days I don't have to rush myself and I could relax more. I also made a better overview of my plan and made some calculations which gives a better view on all of it. Do you also have an idea about Delhi and Bangkok?

Comment: I think I'll let others with more recent experience comment. BTW, the entry ticket (CNY 248) for ZJJ covers three days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say your question fits this site well, since it's more of tripadvisor type.

I'm familiar with all these countries, so I though to put my thoughts. There are many experienced travelers here than myself, so expect some better answers.

### 1. India

You can't "do" India in just 8 days, but it's certainly possible to visit many places and have plenty of Chais in 8 days (in Delhi). Agra is nearby, and I would spend at least two days for the Taj Mahal (including transportation and one day stay there).

Delhi alone is a huge city, with many large districts. You will probably get sick due to food and water there. 2 days would be enough to account for them. Delhi is way better than it used to be. Many people just overrate Delhi as unsafe or troublesome.

From Delhi, it would take almost two days to go to the other point in the golden triangle: Jaipur. Delhi and Mumbai (DEL and BOM) are the main airports, so any flights originating from other airports would cost you a lot more. I personally like Mumbai, and that's another day's train travel. A trip to India isn't complete without riding the train.  If your departing flight is in the night, keep Uber or a taxi handy. Finding a taxi or public transport to the airport is difficult there.

### 2. Thailand

If you plan to visit Thailand again, 8 days is more than enough for Bangkok. You wouldn't be able to go to Chiang Mai, or Somewhere north, but I don't see any reason to not try Pattaya or any southern regions.

Without breaking the budget, you can even go to Malaysia. AirAsiaX provides much cheap tickets to China, and most nationals have visa free or on-arrival entry

Two days for a river cruise + temples other side of the river. Other places are quick visits. There are many resources online about Bangkok. Stock up some clothing and food while you are at Bangkok.

### 3. China

I'm not going to write more about China since you have spent months there. 5 days wasn't really enough for me for Beijing. 
Sunrise view from the park outside forbidden city is very hard to catch in this season. I would squeeze my Bangkok days and give more to Beijing.

---

Doing many countries in a single trip is definitely fun. You wouldn't be riding a train to different countries, but it feels badass to ask the lady in the next bunk which country you are in right now. (Try it on a Bangkok, Singapore, Kuala Lampur train!).

Make sure you have a backup credit card to rebook any flights if you miss any.

If you have never been to Bangkok or Delhi before, be prepared to deal with some scams. I'm not sure about your visiting dates. However, it's monsoon season in India, and visiting specially the southern places is very difficult these days. March and April would be perfect. There are holy festivals (seen in Bollywood movies?), and foreigners are welcome to put a load of of colored powder in strangers' faces!).

Visiting India without a solid plan is somewhat challenging. I'm from South Asia so I'm used to the customs there in India, but I personally know many who struggled to get around India.

Comment: I'm not really planning on staying longer in Beijing because I've been/seen quite everything there, but I just want to have some deja vu moments there. Originally I only wanted to visit Beijing, Zhangjiajie and a few other cities in China. But then I thought, why not visit outside of China? And I can't take more days of from work so I don't think I could also add Malaysia to the list. Which place do you think takes longest to see, Delhi or Bangkok? I would rather visit all these countries for 1 month each, but I just don't have the time for it. & what do you mean with keep Uber or taxi handy?

Comment: Uber(X) worked well in both Delhi and Beijing, and their prices are reasonable, even by local standards. I can't speak Hindi or Chinese, but I could manage to find a decent taxi using the Uber app.

Comment: I think Delhi and Bangkok are almost same. If you are up for a challenge and to get mixed with locals, Delhi would be better.